# Checking a checkbox must hold the text value of its inline div

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner in angularjs. I would like to get experts advice in making my code better.

I have a requirement, where there is iteration of checkbox. And each check box should hold 2 div elements with some id, one is holding **description** and another holding price.

If I am checking multiple check box, then an json string object should be generated like below with watever correcpoding checkbox is ticked

`var jsonString =` `[ {selectedCheckBoxId:2, description:"Bread", price: "$2"}, {selectedCheckBoxId:4, description:"Burger", price: "$5"} ]`

I am totally new to front end. So learning things doing examples. Please if possible show me in js fiddle.

You suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Please dont miss understand for those who felt I didnt do a Proper research. There is some deadline hitting me with less time to spare. So asking experts tips. I request you should consider a beginner to grow with clearing queries. Let people who feels to help me can come forward and do. Others please dont discourage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be help u.

```
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in Items track by item.selectedCheckBoxId">
   <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selectedCheckBoxId" ng-     click="update($event,$index)"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

and in your controller :

```
 app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){

 $scope.Items = [ {selectedCheckBoxId:2, description:"Bread", price: "$2"}, 
              {selectedCheckBoxId:4, description:"Burger", price: "$5"},
              {selectedCheckBoxId:5, description:"Bread2", price: "$2"},
              {selectedCheckBoxId:6, description:"Burger6", price: "$5"}
             ];
$scope.data = [];

$scope.update = function($event,id){
 var checkbox = $event.target;
  var action = (checkbox.checked ? 'add' : 'remove');
  updateData(action,id);
};

$scope.updateData = function(action, id){
  if(action == "add")
   var object = {$scope.Items[id]};
    $scope.data.push(object);
  }else{
    // if object find in data remove it
    }

 });
```

Comment: This was really usefull. Its not that, I didnt do proper research. I wanted a best methodology to solve this. Really thankful to let me know that $event & $index can be used for this.